# передача файлов с клиента на сервер любой длинны Java-Socket API

Tags: java, файлы, сокет

Я могу сейчас передавать файлы меджу клиентом и сервером следующим образом:

Клиент связан с сервером с помощью ТСП подключения, и клиент высылает на сервер байты файла в виде переменной `String` таким образом:

```
// получаю файл
Path file = Paths.get(fileName);
// записываю байты файла в таблицу байтов
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file);
// получаю байты в виде строки
String dataStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
```

Дальше сервер передает эти байты в микросервис который нужен что бы принять байты, создать новый файл, и записать в него полученные байты. Вот как то так выглядт код в микросервисе для передачи файлов:

```
// создаю пустой файл
FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(login + "/" + serverNameFile);
// записываю полученные байты от клиента в виде строки в таблицу байтов
byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(dataFile);
// записываю байты в новый файл
file.write(data);
```

У меня все работает, но для файлов с ограниченной длинной. Как можна было бы улучшить мой код для файлов любой длинны? То есть, можно ли высылать байты в цикле, до тех пор пока они будут считываться с файла и так же в цикле по чуть-чуть их записывать в файл?

У меня сейчас все так работает что клиент подключается у серверу, сервер подключается к микросервису "Передача файлов" - этот микросервис записывает байты и возвращает ответ серверу, а сервер возвращает ответ клиенту, как то так. И когда микросервис вернул ответ серверу, то между ними соединения опять нету, нужно ждать пока клиента опять захочет выслать файл, и сервер заново покдлючится к микросервису "Передача файлов".

Answer (score 0):

Этот код я использую для отправки файла с сервера.

```
                    File file = new File(file_name);
                    long length = file.length();
                    
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[4000 * 1024];
                    InputStream in1 = new FileInputStream(file);
                    OutputStream out1 = connection.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                    
                    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
                    buf.putLong(length);
                    System.out.println(length);
                    
                    // И отправляем
                    out1.write(buf.array());
                    System.out.println(buf.array());
                        
                    int count;
                    while ((count = in1.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                        out1.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        System.out.println(count);

                        
                    }
                    out1.close();
                    in1.close();
                    System.out.println("file send");
                    break;
```

А этот для приема на телефоне

```
                                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();

                                // Читаем размер файл
                                byte[] fileSizeBuf = new byte[8];
                                in.read(fileSizeBuf, 0, 8);
                                // Преобразовываем в long
                                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
                                buf.put(fileSizeBuf);
                                buf.flip();
                                long fileSize = buf.getLong();

                               


                                File internalStorageDir = getFilesDir();
                                alice = new File(internalStorageDir,"папка на 
                                телефоне"+"/"+List.file_name + ".zip");
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(alice);
                                byte[] bytes = new byte[4000 * 1024];


                                int count;
                                double size=0;
                                while (fileSize >0 && (count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                                    size += count;
                                    double all = (size / fileSize)*100;
                                    //проерить целостность файла
                                    System.out.println(all);
                                    System.out.println("пришло за цикл: "+count);
                                    System.out.println("всего пришло: "+size);
                                    // Write a line to the file
                                    //fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                                    fos.write(bytes, 0, count);
                                }

                                fos.close();
                                in.close();
                                output.close();

                               
                                 break;
```

надеюсь  алгоритм вам понятен.